# My MacBook Pro won’t let me erase my disk

Tags: macos, disk-utility, apfs

I'm trying to delete all the data off my MacBook Pro. I pressed command+r, went to disk utilities, selected my disk in the slot to the left, went to the erase tab. The "erase" button is faded so I can't click it. Format is at Mac OS Extended (Journaled) already, but it's also faded out. I tried command+alt+r aswell it also says disk can’t be erased because it is not mounted and when I try to mount it I get an error message.

When I tried to go recoveryHD by pressing command it keeps on restarting. What is happening ? How can I fix this?

My drive is a SATA drive

Comment: Which MacBook Pro do you have and which version of macOS?

Comment: I have a mid 2013 MacBook Pro using the Catalina OS

Comment: You can't delete the volume you're running from. Are you planning to reinstall a new clean copy of macOS after erasing it? If so, I'd recommend [creating a bootable installer flash drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372), and doing the erase-and-reinstall from that.

Comment: Hello I tried it using a bootable installer, it still allow me to erase the disk